# Hapi.js load plugins in order

Tags: node.js, plugins, hapi.js

I am new to Hapi.js and I am stuck a point trying to figure out how can we load plugins in order in a Hapi.js setup.

For example: I have 2 plugins **Plugin1** and **Plugin2**. Lets say **Plugin2**  is dependent on **Plugin1** and cannot run until **Plugin1** is executed.

It seems like loading these plugins in 2 separate server.register methods or with a single server.register (with array of plugins) seems to be executing the plugins code in parallel...

So, can some one help me with how can I load plugins in order...thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will want to use [`server.dependency`](http://hapijs.com/api#serverdependencydependencies-after) as a solution.

With it, you can declare a plugin dependent upon another and if the dependency is missing (or you accidentally create a circular dependency) your server will throw.

With this, you have an opportunity to use the `after` function to delay execution of code in **Plugin2** that must wait until **Plugin1** is loaded.

You can also see discussion titled "[Inconsistent plugin load order](https://github.com/hapijs/glue/issues/19)" on the glue github repo or this one called "[Server start can fail due to plugins not loaded in the right order](https://github.com/jedireza/aqua/issues/36)" from aqua for additional info and details.

Comment: That should be singular: `server.dependency()`. The link should be http://hapijs.com/api#serverdependencydependencies-after

Answer (score 5):

You have a few options available to you.

You could take a look at [Glue](https://github.com/hapijs/glue). You can use the array syntax for plugins to load plugins in a specific order:

```
var Glue = require('glue');

var manifest = {
    server: {
        cache: 'redis'
    },
    connections: [
        {
            port: 8000,
            labels: ['web']
        },
        {
            port: 8001,
            labels: ['admin']
        }
    ],
    plugins: [
        { 'Plugin1': null },
        { 'Plugin2': null }
    ]
};


var options = {
    relativeTo: __dirname
};

Glue.compose(manifest, options, function (err, server) {

    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    server.start(function () {

        console.log('Hapi days!');
    });
});
```

This is same as doing the following without the use of Glue:

```
server.register(require('Plugin1'), function (err) {

    server.register(require('Plugin2'), function (err) {

        server.start(function () {

            console.log('Hapi days!');
        });
    });
});
```

Having order-dependent plugins is messy though and hapi offers a better way to fix this. You can use [`server.dependency()`](http://hapijs.com/api#serverdependencydependencies-after) to explictly express a plugin's dependency on another plugin. So inside Plugin2 you could do:

```
var ready = function (server, next) {

    server.route({
        ...
    });

    next();
};

exports.register = function (server, options, next) {

    server.dependency('Plugin1', ready);
    next();
};

exports.register.attributes = { 
    name: 'Plugin2',
    version: '0.0.1'
};
```

With this approach, it doesn't matter about the plugin registration order. This is great for big apps where there's lot of plugins worked on by different people or teams.

Answer (score 0):

You can register your plugins in order after you created your server instance.

For example:

```
const server = new Hapi.Server(ConfigUtils.resolve(Config.Server));


await server.register([
    PluginUtils.bootstrap(AwsPlugin, ConfigUtils.resolve(Plugin.Aws) ),
    PluginUtils.bootstrap(OrmPlugin, ConfigUtils.resolve(Plugin.Orm) ),
    PluginUtils.bootstrap(SessionPlugin, ConfigUtils.resolve(Plugin.Session) ),
]);
```